# An CommandButton action auto execute many times on load

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm writing a JSF page,however, a commandbutton calls its action many times on page load,but no one clicked it...this mess up my whole progress...

HTML:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
<h:form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>姓名：</td>
            <td><p:inplace editor="true"><p:inputText value="#{user.name}"/></p:inplace></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>联系方式：</td>
            <td><p:inplace editor="true"><p:inputText value="#{user.phone}"/></p:inplace></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>性别：</td>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{user.gender}"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>身份证号：</td>
            <td><p:inplace editor="true"><p:inputText value="#{user.pid}"/></p:inplace></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="position:absolute; right:30px;"><p:commandButton value="删除" action="#{info.removeUser()}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</h:form>
```

java:

```
public void removeUser(){
    System.out.println("Current tab:"+index +" Removed............");
    users.remove(Integer.parseInt(index));
}
```

here the "index" is the current tab in accordionPanel,which is a String...

Fisrt time to ask question here,maybe I omitted some infomation...

Answer (score 1):

That can happen if you forgot to declare the `p` XML namespage in the view.

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

If you forget to declare the `p` XML namespace, then all `p:xxx` tags are treated as plain text. All EL expressions in the attributes are executed immediately as if they are embedded in plain text. This also includes the `#{info.removeUser()}` expression. That "many times" is most likely the same amount as the EL expression appears in the view.

Comment: I think I have the p declaration...now I put the commandbutton in another place in the page and it works normally

Comment: It also happened to me when using xmlns of JSF 2.2 in a JSF 2.1 project.